# Deleting Salesforce Scratch Orgs that do not appear in force:org:list

Tags: salesforce, sfdx, salesforce-sfdx

I'm bumping into the maximum number of active Scratch Orgs:

> ERROR running force:org:create:  The signup request failed because this organization has reached its active scratch org limit

But I only see 02 active Scratch Orgs:

```
sfdx force:org:list
```

Then, I run a SOQL query to extract records from the ScratchOrgInfo object:

```
sfdx force:data:soql:query --query "SELECT Id, Username, Status, LoginUrl, ExpirationDate FROM ScratchOrgInfo ORDER BY ExpirationDate DESC"
```

Now, I can not delete those orgs even using the usernames of the "hidden" Scratch Orgs:

```
sfdx force:org:delete -u xxx@xxx.com
```

> ERROR running force:org:delete:  No org configuration found for name xxx@xxx.com

My question is: is there a way to delete Scratch Orgs using the "ORG ID" value?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove these orgs by logging in to your Dev Hub and navigating to the Active Scratch Orgs tab. Select a list view (or create one) that allows you to view the relevant scratch orgs. Then delete each unwanted scratch org's Active Scratch Org record to enqueue it for deletion.